# Provide parameters to OpenCV C++ program in ROS from external file

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a program using OpenCV C++ interface in ROS. I want to provide parameters used by the program from external file(not sure which format will be apt).

Say, I use the threshold function in the program, **instead of changing the threshold value each time in the program,make and then run**, I want the program to fetch the threshold value from a file so that **if I wish to change any value, I could do it in the external file.**

I want this because I think it will be helpful to a third-person who can just change the various parameters in the file and observe the result rather than opening the program, change values,make and run (*Sometimes the third person may not be a programmer and just wishes to see the results, in that case he would not know the technicalities of where to change parameters in the program*)

I am new to ROS. I am using Fuerte. Is there any way to do this in ROS ??

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58339/provide-parameters-to-opencv-c++-program-in-ros-from-external-file/) by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More specifically, check out roslaunch and the ability to import parameters via yaml files.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/rosparam

And a sample of how to include the parameters:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects#roslaunch.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-Roslaunch_tips_for_larger_projects.Parameters.2C_namespaces.2C_and_yaml_files

So after you change the file, you only need to run in the command line: "roslaunch package something.launch"

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-03-17**:
This is definitely the best approach.  You can also specify command-line args to launch files, allowing you to specify the YAML (config) file to use each time you launch the node.  Also, you can load a set of default values from a YAML file and use cmd-line args to override indiv. params at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS provides functionality for exactly that purpose. The [Paramter Server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Parameter%20Server). Have a look at that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1